# Tracking Java native code and dll interaction

Tags: java-native-interface

I am accessing a DLL file from java code.
But I am getting the below exception.

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /Default/ws/Services/LegacyCWS: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: x:\xxx\xxxx\xxx\xxx\jboss\ext_libs\aesdpapi4j.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at aesdpapi.AesDataProtectionAPI.<clinit>(AesDataProtectionAPI.java:144)
```

I want to verify if there is a memory leak when this exception occurs, and why this exception occurs.

Comment: "*[...] Why this exception occurs.*" - The error message is quite clear about this: "*`Can't find dependent libraries`*".

Comment: I have all the neccessary files updated in the lib. But still getting this msg.

Comment: The typical tool for solving these issues is http://www.dependencywalker.com/ . Run it on aesdpapi4j.dll and see if it also reports missing dependencies. Make sure to grab the correct version of dependency walker (32bits or 64bits) according to your DLL's architecture.

Comment: checked with depedencywalker as well, it gives error while reading this dll file.